# Why am I Getting the Error: Invalid Hook Call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm receiving a cannot read props of undefined. I'm trying to destructure props but I need the hook calls. Is there a way for me to destructure props in a function or another way to resolve this issue?

ProductBrowse.jsx is formatting the products:

```
    const ProductBrowse = () => {

    const { id, name, img, store, price, desc, inCart } = this.props.product;
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const openModal = () => {
      setOpen(!open);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
      setOpen(!open);
    };

    return (
      <Box border={1} borderRadius={3}>
        <Card>
          <CardActionArea>
             <ProductModal
              open={open}
              onClick={() => openModal()}
              onClose={() => closeModal()}
              onSave={() => closeModal()}
              productName={name}
              productDesc={desc}
            />
            <CardHeader
              title={name}
              subheader={formatCurrency(price)}
            />
            <CardMedia
              image={img}
              alt={desc}
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' component='p'>
                {desc}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
          <CardActions>
            <Button size='small' /*To Checkout*/>BUY NOW</Button>
            <Button
              size='small'
              onClick={() => {
                console.log('Added to Cart');
              }}
            >
              ADD TO CART
            </Button>
            <Button size='small'>REVIEW</Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </Box>
    );
  }
```

Comment: where u used the hooks. Hooks are only work with functional component. Make sure u are using it in functional component.

Comment: When I use a functional component I get the error cannot read props of undefined. How do I destructure props in a function?

Comment: I wrote the first 2 lines like this and it appears to be working. Is this the correct way to destructure a functional component?

const ProductBrowse = (props) => {
    const { id, name, img, store, price, desc, inCart } = props.product;

Comment: @ocom: yes, it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your class based component to a functional component like this:

```
const ProductBrowse = ({ product }) => {

   const { id, name, img, store, price, desc, inCart } = product;
   ...
}
export default ProductBrowse;
```

As you can see, the product props are being destructured. The entire props object is available if you were to provide more props and want to use them as well.

i.e.

```
const ProductBrowse = (props) => {

   const { id, name, img, store, price, desc, inCart } = props.product;
   ...
}
export default ProductBrowse;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use hooks in class based components. Please refer [converted functional component](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cache-m9del?file=/src/ProductBrowse.js)

```
const ProductBrowse = props => {
  const { id, name, img, store, price, desc, inCart } = props.product;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const openModal = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <Box border={1} borderRadius={3}>
      <Card>
        <CardActionArea>
          {<ProductModal
            open={open}
            onClick={() => openModal()}
            onClose={() => closeModal()}
            onSave={() => closeModal()}
            productName={name}
            productDesc={desc}
          /> }
          <CardHeader title={name} subheader={formatCurrency(price)} />
          <CardMedia image={img} alt={desc} /> 
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              {desc}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" /*To Checkout*/>BUY NOW</Button>
          <Button
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              console.log("Added to Cart");
            }}
          >
            ADD TO CART
          </Button>
          <Button size="small">REVIEW</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Also while using this components pass product as it's props as you are destructuring in ProductBrowse component. It should be like this:

```
<ProductBrowse products={this.products} />
```